# Is it possible to have entanglement with different sized parties or with more than 2 parties?

Tags: entanglement

All the entanglement I've see is between 2 parties that have the same number of qubits. Is it possible to have entanglement where each party has a different number of qubits? Is it possible to have entanglement between 3 parties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! Look up [multipartite entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_entanglement).

An example of an entangled system among $n$ $d$-dimensional qudits is a [GHZ state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenberger%E2%80%93Horne%E2%80%93Zeilinger_state):
$$|\mathrm{GHZ}\rangle\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt d}\sum_{k=1}^d \lvert \underbrace{k,k,...,k}_n\rangle
\equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt d}\sum_{k=1}^d \bigotimes_{j=1}^n \lvert k\rangle.$$
You can think of this as a generalisation of a [Bell state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state), which you might have heard of.

Another notorious genuinely multipartite entangled state is a [$W$ state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_state). In the simplest case of three qubits this is
$$|W\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}(|001\rangle+|010\rangle+|100\rangle).$$

Entanglement between systems of different dimensions is also possible. For example, if you have a qubit and a qutrit, you can consider a state such as
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\left[|0\rangle\otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\left(|0\rangle+|1\rangle+|2\rangle\right)
+ |1\rangle\otimes\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)\right].$$
A context in which you commonly encounter states with entanglement/correlation between a low-dimensional and a high-dimensional degree of freedom is for example a [quantum walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_walk) (though one doesn't usually study the entanglement properties of the produced states when dealing with these).